# randomly generating colors with php

Tags: php, colors

So I'm working on making my header change color everyday, and I was attempting to create this using a random color. There are 2 colors in the header and I am making them complimentary colors. the first color is generated randomly, and then the second is modified by changing the Hue via 150`. The problem is when certain colors are chosen, they could be either too vibrant or dark. I have a check running so that I can slightly control the brightness value, but there are still some colors that are too bright ( for instance extreme yellows ). I'l post my code below. Any help or suggestions is appreciated! Thanks!

```
// grab a random color on hue 
$h = rand(0,360);

// color values 50-120 tend to be extremely bright, 
// make adjustments to the S and L accordingly
// a better solution is available?
if ($h > 50 && $h < 120) {
    $s = rand(60,80);
    $l = rand(30,50);
} else {
    $s = rand(60,90);
    $l = rand(38,63);
}

// declare string to place as css in file for primary color           
$randomColor = "hsl(". $h .",". $s ."%,". $l ."%)";

// declare degree for secondary color (30 = analogous, 150 = complimentary)
$degree = 150;

// point to secondary color randomly on either side of chart        
$bool = rand(0,1);
if ($bool) {
    $x = $degree;
} else {
    $x = -$degree;
} 

// set value of the new hue
$nh = $h + $degree;

// if the new hue is above 360 or below 0, make adjustments accordingly
if ($nh > 360) {
    $nh -= 360;
}
if ($nh < 0 ) {
    $nh = 360 - $nh;
}

// set the secondary color
$secondaryColor = "hsl(". abs($h + $x) .",". $s ."%,". $l ."%)";
```

This seems very simple and I'm sure there is a better method. I looked around, but all I noticed were the basic formula's via degrees for the hue etc. Thanks again!

Comment: why don't you just use an array of color values and use `array_rand()`

Comment: I'm not super-good with color theory, but if you're simply worried about colors being too light/dark in an H/S/L color space couldn't you just put upper and lower bounds on the L value?

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a question of which colors you deem acceptable for viewing. This certainly isn't an optimal solution but it's an approach that is readable at least (it's also *slightly* more random than your original, if you even care about that):

```
function randColor() {
    return array( rand(0,360), rand(0,100), rand(0,100) );
}

function isAcceptableColor($colorArr) {
    // return true if the color meets your criteria
}

do {
    $color = randColor();
} while ( ! isAcceptableColor($color) );
```

Comment: I'm sure you mean `while (!isAcceptableColor($color))`, don't you?

Comment: I sure do :) If I hadn't put that comment in the `isAcceptableColor` method I probably could have gotten away with the excuse of "it depends what is returned by the function" but you got me. Thanks